# How to bind parameter in sub query in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a sub-query in join in which I am using where clause, but its giving me the error

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.id' in 'where clause'

Below is my query:

```
Product::leftJoin(
                'categories',
                'products.category_id',
                '=',
                'categories.id'
            )
            ->join('vendor_products', function ($join) {
                $join->on(
                    'products.id',
                    '=',
                    'vendor_products.product_id'
                )
            })
            ->leftJoin('brand_products', function ($join) {
                    $join->on(
                        'products.id',
                        '=',
                        'brand_products.product_id'
                    )->on(
                        'brand_products.brand_id',
                        '=',
                        DB::raw('(
                            SELECT brand_id FROM 
                            (SELECT brand_id, COUNT(brand_id) productCount 
                            FROM brand_products
                            where brand_products.product_id = products.id
                            inner join brand on brand_products.brand_id = brand.id
                            GROUP BY brand_id order by productCount desc, DATE(brand.created_at) asc limit 1) as results)')
                    );
            })
            ->get();
```

this is the line causing error `where brand_products.product_id = products.id`.

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

In your raw Query add products table as well in `FROM` like this

```
DB::raw('(
        SELECT brand_id FROM 
        (SELECT brand_id, COUNT(brand_id) productCount 
        FROM brand_products,products,brand
        where brand_products.product_id = products.id
        inner join brand on brand_products.brand_id = brand.id
        GROUP BY brand_id order by productCount desc, DATE(brand.created_at) asc limit 1) as results)')
```

I hope it'll work

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join brand on brand_products.brand_id = brand.id

Comment: @HarrisKhan put the inner join line above the where clause

Comment: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'brand_id' in field list is ambiguous receiving that error now

Comment: I also try with brand_products.brand_id but no luck

Comment: @HarrisKhan add brand alongside products and brand_products in the FROM section

Comment: could you edit your answer please so that I can see what exactly I need to change

Comment: @HarrisKhan Yes sure, Check the answer now

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'brand' error

Comment: @HarrisKhan it is saying that you don't have any table named brand, so check your database is there any table named  brand ??

Comment: @HarrisKhan Maybe the table name would be brands ??